# how to make gvlogic condition shortcode work on widget?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, gravityforms

I am trying use GVLOGIC to show data into a widget. A code that would work inside gravity forms is not working in widget in spite of saying that would work wordpress everywhere. Can anyone help me where i am missing?

My goal is to use this in order to indicate users when some field is empty and need user to click and open a form for update.

In this user case, `{user:gf_e_data}` is "2" but get always false on condition on this example

Cant understand why conditional does not work with and {user:var} variables. 
If i use, for exemple [gvlogic logged_in="true" ... ] it would work.
Already tried some statement variations around conditions but without any positive result.

```
[gvlogic if="{user:gf_e_data}" is="2"]
true condition will show some data
[else]
false condition will show some data // would insert here a link for update this field
[/gvlogic]
```

All known true conditions seems to fail and get false.

Is there another why to conditionally control some alert messages in user dashboard when some action is need on user update?

Answer (score 0):

Well. 
It was real simple changing user metadata variable {user:gf_e_data} to a form field (update entry) and putting it inside gravityview in widget.
Thanks anyway!